# RoR, place value from select_tag in params hash

Tags: activerecord, associations, update-attributes, html-select

I am confused about the accepted way to update an association. Let's assume there are 2 models, Worker and Factory.  When editing a Worker, the user is presented with a select_tag that contains a list of factories. My issue is the fact that the factory_id is not in the params[:worker][:factory_id] hash, but is instead in the params[:factory_id] hash.  The end effect is that when my worker.update_attributes is called, the factory_id isn't updated because it isn't in the :worker hash.

My question is should I even be trying to get my factory_id into the params[:worker] hash through modifying my erb file, or should I be manually updating the value at params[:worker][:factory_id] with the value found in params[:factory_id]. Below is my erb code just in case there is something different I should be doing there.  Also, the Factory class has_many workers and the Worker class belongs_to the Factory class if that helps.

```
<div>
  <%= label_tag :factory , "Factory" %><br />
  <%= select_tag "factory_id",
     options_from_collection_for_select(@state_factories... %>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in the ERB file:

```
<%= select_tag "worker[factory_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(@state_factories... %>
```

Although, I'd use the select helper:

```
<%= select "worker", "factory_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@state_factories... %>
```

As that would automatically select the factory on edit.

Comment: That was it.  Would you mind explaining why you choose select over select_tag ?  The results from searching "select helper vs select_tag" are kind of scant.  Thanks again !

Comment: Sure. If you set the @worker object in the controller, the select helper will look at the object and automatically select the corresponding option in the rendered html. The usual way to generate the list is to just pass in an array of strings, and let the helper generate the options. Without knowing your factories object, something like this might work:

https://gist.github.com/4402711

The select_tag is just a basic wrapper around the html builder - you need to pass a string of <option> tags yourself.